# Filling missing dates in pandas groupby with aggregate functions

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a dataframe where each id may have gaps. I'd like to fill in missing dates (with NaN values) within each group before using aggregate functions as they don't seem to go by date, but I'm getting the error below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2014-08-01',
                            '2014-08-02', 
                            '2014-08-03',
                            '2014-08-04',
                            '2014-08-10',
                            '2014-08-15',
                            '2014-08-12',
                            '2014-08-15',
                            '2014-08-20',
                            '2014-08-21',
                            '2014-08-22',                            
                            '2014-08-30',                            
                           ], 
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 

                   'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',  'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.sort_values('date', ascending=True).groupby('id').set_index('date').resample('1D').rolling(2).mean()
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) for add consecutive datetimes:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df1 = (df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
        .set_index('date')
        .groupby('id')
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('d').rolling(2).mean())
```

---

```
print (df1)

               value
id date             
a  2014-08-01    NaN
   2014-08-02    1.5
   2014-08-03    2.5
   2014-08-04    3.5
   2014-08-05    NaN
   2014-08-06    NaN
   2014-08-07    NaN
   2014-08-08    NaN
   2014-08-09    NaN
   2014-08-10    NaN
   2014-08-11    NaN
   2014-08-12    NaN
   2014-08-13    NaN
   2014-08-14    NaN
   2014-08-15    NaN
b  2014-08-12    NaN
   2014-08-13    NaN
   2014-08-14    NaN
   2014-08-15    NaN
   2014-08-16    NaN
   2014-08-17    NaN
   2014-08-18    NaN
   2014-08-19    NaN
   2014-08-20    NaN
   2014-08-21    9.5
   2014-08-22   10.5
   2014-08-23    NaN
   2014-08-24    NaN
   2014-08-25    NaN
   2014-08-26    NaN
   2014-08-27    NaN
   2014-08-28    NaN
   2014-08-29    NaN
   2014-08-30    NaN
```

---

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df2 = (df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
        .set_index('date')
        .groupby('id')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('d').rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()))
```

---

```
print (df2)
id  date      
a   2014-08-01     1.0
    2014-08-02     1.5
    2014-08-03     2.5
    2014-08-04     3.5
    2014-08-05     4.0
    2014-08-06     NaN
    2014-08-07     NaN
    2014-08-08     NaN
    2014-08-09     NaN
    2014-08-10     5.0
    2014-08-11     5.0
    2014-08-12     NaN
    2014-08-13     NaN
    2014-08-14     NaN
    2014-08-15     6.0
b   2014-08-12     7.0
    2014-08-13     7.0
    2014-08-14     NaN
    2014-08-15     8.0
    2014-08-16     8.0
    2014-08-17     NaN
    2014-08-18     NaN
    2014-08-19     NaN
    2014-08-20     9.0
    2014-08-21     9.5
    2014-08-22    10.5
    2014-08-23    11.0
    2014-08-24     NaN
    2014-08-25     NaN
    2014-08-26     NaN
    2014-08-27     NaN
    2014-08-28     NaN
    2014-08-29     NaN
    2014-08-30    12.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

If need forward filling missing values:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s = (df.sort_values('date', ascending=True)
        .set_index('date')
        .groupby('id')['value']
        .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('d', method='ffill')))
```

---

```
print (s)
id  date      
a   2014-08-01     1
    2014-08-02     2
    2014-08-03     3
    2014-08-04     4
    2014-08-05     4
    2014-08-06     4
    2014-08-07     4
    2014-08-08     4
    2014-08-09     4
    2014-08-10     5
    2014-08-11     5
    2014-08-12     5
    2014-08-13     5
    2014-08-14     5
    2014-08-15     6
b   2014-08-12     7
    2014-08-13     7
    2014-08-14     7
    2014-08-15     8
    2014-08-16     8
    2014-08-17     8
    2014-08-18     8
    2014-08-19     8
    2014-08-20     9
    2014-08-21    10
    2014-08-22    11
    2014-08-23    11
    2014-08-24    11
    2014-08-25    11
    2014-08-26    11
    2014-08-27    11
    2014-08-28    11
    2014-08-29    11
    2014-08-30    12
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use agg with multiple functions instead of apply?

Comment: @Bob - hmm, if need in ouput all datetimes it is problem, because `agg` return aggreagte values. but it depends what need exactly.

Comment: I meant to use .agg instead of .mean to get the output of multiple functions